# Stack - Where's the value stored for valuetypes?

Tags: c#, memory-management, stack

```
void main()
{
    int x = 5; // stack-allocated
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

I'm aware of that `x` is stack-allocated. But what's actually stored in the stack about `x`? Do it hold the "real value", or the address to some place in memory which contains the value?

Comment: Mr Lippert would probably warn you, that "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR", x is stack allocated. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx. (What I mean is: you are asking about an implementation detail that can silently change between versions, implementations, platforms or weekdays.)

Comment: While people often (quite rightly) point out that this is an implementation detail, I still think it's important to understand what the CLR is doing under the hood. This is a good question +1. In this case, the actual value of x would be stored in the stack (or possibly, in a register).

Comment: **Why do you believe x is stack allocated?** I agree that it *might* be stack allocated. But x could be *enregistered*, since it is 32 bits in size and its address is never taken. Or it could be *elided* since it is a single-assignment local with constant value. If you were to add a lambda closed over x, it could be hoisted to a field of a closure class allocated on the heap.

Comment: To clarify: that's not a rhetorical question. I am interested to learn why it is that people believe things without justification. Something misled you into believing that x was *guaranteed* to be stack allocated and *never* enregistered, elided or hoisted. What was that thing that led you to that unjustified belief?

Comment: @EricLippert, I'm reading the book "CLR via C# - Third edition" by Jeffrey Richter at the moment. The book does only touch the subjects stack, and heap shortly. According to the book (I might have misunderstood something), then value-types = stack and classes = heap. I've never, ever heard about the register and that it can be used for storage too, is there any particular good papers that explains it in detail? And what do you mean by elided? - I'm aware of that I don't need to know how the stack/heap/register works in order to program, but I do want to know the how instead of just the why.

Comment: Many people are of the false belief that value types always go on the stack and reference types always go on the heap. I would be surprised if Jeff's book says that, but I haven't actually read it. The truth is that *the lifetime of a storage location has nothing whatsoever to do with its type*. Storage locations are allocated from a short-term pool when their lifetimes are known to be not longer than the current activation, and from a long-term pool otherwise.

Comment: To *elide* is a grammatical term which means to eliminate a word without changing the meaning of a sentence. If I said to you "I have some towels that need washed", you would understand what I meant even though I elided the words "I", "to" and "be" in "I have some towels that I need to be washed". By extension, an elision in computer science is the elimination of an entity such that the meaning of a program is not changed. The variable x in your program can be elided; it is useful only for its *value*, which is known at compile time, and not useful *as a storage location*.

Comment: If you are interested in learning the truth about memory management in .NET -- to a reasonable degree of approximation, at least -- try reading my articles on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/memory+management/.  In particular, "The Stack Is An Implementation Detail" and "The Truth About Value Types" will help.

Comment: @EricLippert, Thanks! I'll give it a shot, and see if I can make any sense of it :)

Comment: @Eric, please feel free to edit my answer if I've made any gaffes.  You're a much better writer than I. :-)

Comment: @JeffreyHantin: I think your answer is fine!

Comment: @EricLippert, Just to clarify: Do an int have a memory address? I mean.. they can't just be stored as raw values, without taking any memory. Whoever I ask says that it's just a value, and dosen't mention anything about a memory address. Is the reason simply that, it's stored in the memory that's allocated for the stack/register, and therefore it just uses the memory in there, and not a pointer to some place on the heap?

Comment: Also: http://xense.org/stack.jpg - Am I all wrong about how it's working?

Comment: @ebb: Of course they can be stored as raw values without consuming any memory.  **The storage could be a register**.  Registers do not have addresses. Now, *typically* a storage location is associated with a particular *managed pointer* inside either the long-term store (the heap) or the temporary store (the stack). But regardless of whether it has an address or not, the storage location for an int contains *the int*. It does not contain *a reference to the int's real storage location.* That's the difference between a value type and a reference type.

Comment: @ebb: Regarding your diagram: that's pretty good. The details of point 4 aren't quite the way I would express them, but you've got the right idea.

Comment: @EricLippert, Good point regarding the register, should've thought of that... Just to dig a little deeper: what's the reason for that a value type can be saved with it's respective raw value without consuming any memory? Is it that all value types consists of bits? - But even then.. shouldn't those bits take up memory? I simply don't understand how you can store something without consuming any memory... - Also how would you express point 4 on my diagram :)? (so many silly questions... now when I have the chance to ask a true expert in the field, I want to learn/understand as much as possible).

Comment: Registers aren't *memory*; they don't have *addresses*.   They're storage locations, but when you say that you have 8GB of physical memory, or 4GB of virtual address space, or whatever, the couple dozen registers aren't counted as "memory". They're not addressable.

Comment: Good example with registers.. I guess my question is actually: **HOW** can you store value-types, with their raw value, and not consume any memory - but you can't do the same with a reference-type? I know it's an absurd question.. but it feels like I'm missing something extremely basic.

Comment: int Example(int y) {int x=y+1; return x;} I'm guessing a bit, but in this case it is not necessary to store x any where in memory. y value can be loaded into registry, incremented by 1 and then returned. So x consumes storage, but as this storage is not addressable it's not counted as memory. This is a contrived example. Compiler probably optimizes this code (in-lining?).

Comment: @EricLippert, Thanks for the blog posts, examples and your help! It have helped me greatly to understand just a little bit of memory management. I've moved my question about how a value-type dosen't consume any memory, while a reference-type does, to a new question, in order not to spam away this question. Link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706769/why-do-value-types-not-consume-memory-while-reference-types-does

Comment: @ebb: Value types consume *storage*. Temporary storage is allocated from memory pages on the stack or from registers; long-term storage is allocated from memory pages on the heap.

Comment: @EricLippert, So the stack, and the heap actually uses virtual memory? - And value-types DO consume memory from the 1MB reserved memory, when allocated on the stack?. The thing I don't get is that you can store a value-type on a register, without consuming any memory.. I know that a register dosen't even know the word "memory", but.. how do it store the value then?

Comment: The stack and the heap commit pages of virtual memory from the operating system, yes. A register is nothing more than 32 (or 64) bits of storage *directly on the CPU*. The instructions of the machine language only manipulate registers, for the most part.

Comment: @EricLippert, Ah! Makes a lot more sense now. But if a register is nohing more than 32-64 bits of storage, can more than one value-type me saved in there? If yes, how do it address them? (by address I mean how do it refer to the values in there?, if I ex. want the value of variable z in there, but there's also a variable x - how do it know how to get the value of z?) - Also, when a `int` field gets allocated on the heap, how is the value of the field stored? Is it still a raw value (like a normal value-type), or is the value simply a memory address that points to the actual value?

Comment: A 32 bit register can store 32 bits. If you have two variables of 16 bits each, they could both be stored in the same register; this optimization is reasonably common on x86 systems where it is easy to access half a register. You refer to the values in there by referring to the register; assembly-language programming is all about manipulating registers. In a sense, **that's all that the CPU knows how to do is to manipulate registers.**

Comment: An int field on the heap takes 32 bits out of the allocation and stores an int there. It doesn't store a reference to an int. That's why value types are called "value types" -- because we store and copy *values*. That's why reference types are called "reference types" -- because we store and copy *references*. Int is a value type, so it is stored and copied *by value*, regardless of whether it is stored on the heap, the stack, a register, or whatever.

Comment: "You refer to the values in there by referring to the register" - so the way it knows how to grab the value of variable `z`, if there's another variable in that register too, is to access half the register? - Also, just to be sure. When a field/property is allocated on the heap it still get's a memory address, but it's not used? (if that made any sense).

Comment: @ebb:  Yep.  I've never done much significant assembly, but figuring this out doesn't require significant assembly.  It's pretty much the first thing you learn.  For example, if you've got a 16-bit register on the x86 called AX, you can access the high byte of it via the register name AH and the low byte via the register name AL.  If you need a 32-bit register, you might name it EAX.  If you need a 64-bit register, you might try naming it RAX.  The low 32 bits of RAX are EAX.  The low 16 bits of EAX are AX.  Check the Structure section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86

Answer (score 8):

The answer is a resounding "it depends".

One thing is certain: the storage for the local variable `x`, if it exists at all, contains an actual value rather than a reference, because `int` is a value type.

In a no-frills braindead translation, the actual value of `x` (not a pointer or reference to it) is stored in a local variable in the current call's activation record.  The generated IL would be something like this:

```
  .maxstack 1
  .locals init (int32 V_0)

  ldc.i4.5  // push 5 on the evaluation stack
  stloc.0   // pop it into x

  ldloc.0   // now push a copy of x to pass to ...
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

  ret       // return
```

(Note that the `.maxstack` directive is talking about the IL evaluation stack, not necessarily corresponding to the native stack.  The evaluation stack, if shallow, is often kept in registers by JIT-compiled code.)

In most current implementations of the CLR, activation records and their local variables will be stored on the native stack.  So, naïvely, I suppose `x` could be thought of as having its value stored on the stack.

In an optimizing compilation (or optimizing JIT-translation) of the above code, no local variable storage may exist in the IL at all.  After all, why allocate local variable storage to store it in, then waste two instructions playing with that local variable,  when you're never going to need it again?  It can be inlined away as a constant parameter to `WriteLine`:

```
  .maxstack 1
  // Just pass 5 to WriteLine.  No local variables here.
  ldc.i4.5
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  // Bye.
  ret
```

There are more possible complications.  If the function were declared `async` as in the C# 5 CTP, or if `x` were captured by a lambda expression elsewhere in the function, or if the function was an enumerator built with the `yield return` statement, storage for `x` could end up forced onto the heap: it would become a field in a compiler-generated class, so that the variable's storage can survive tear-down of the stack frame if the closure or continuation escapes local scope.

Answer (score 0):

It stores a real value of x. There is no address or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this line is translated to `ldind.i` command. Specification says:

> 4D  `ldind.i`   Loads the native int value at address addr onto the stack as a native int.

Comment: There's no sensible way this code could generate `ldind.i` -- that's what you use to dereference an `int *` in unsafe code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, since the byte size of `int` will be less or equal that the register size of your processer it is hard to predict a situation where the CLR would choose to do otherwise.

However, whilst this is something that may be of academic interest, it does not need to be considered when writing a program with C#. Its an implementation detail, it can change, the code will still work. The CLR implementers have freed us from this responsibility.